# using functions to move an object in the GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

Please I have a problem with Python functions and return.

```
from graphics import*
win = GraphWin('Me',640,160)


mylist=[]
def move_ob(ob):

    ob.move(4,0)
    return ob

def circle():
    for x in range (10,200,10):
        for y in range (10,200,10):
            c =Circle (Point(x,y),5)
            c.draw(win)
            mylist.append(c)


def main():
    circle()
    win.getMouse()
    move_ob(mylist)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

What I ever I do it gives me this Error

```
ob.move(4,0)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'move'
```

PS: that Library is from the book of John Zelle, learning python basics..

I want to make those circles I make move...

Comment: Please choose a better tittle for next time: It is not necessary to include "Python" (or whatever) in the title as you will already tag it so. Also, please don't put "help" or similar in the title as we all assume you need help other wise you would not be posting a question ;) all kidding aside, this practice is frowned upon by the community and believe it or not it will attract less people to your question. If you feel like editing this title it would be great, but if not. for the next time, thanks!

Comment: thnx, and sorry for the title, I will fix it now for sure...
thnx again!..though I still have problem!  :)!

Comment: Look at the comments in the answer I think it should be fixed now. Thanks for fixing the title and welcome to StackOveflow!! whenever you can please take a minute to review the [FAQ] ok, it is a short read and will help you get quality answers to your questions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing in `mylist`, which is a `list`. Lists have no idea what `move` is.

I assume you want to move all the circles in the list. Therefore, you might want:

```
for circleObject in mylist:
    move_ob(circle)
```

Rather than `move_ob(mylist)`.

Comment: That'll work (just tried it), but I'd avoid rebinding circle.

Comment: thanks for the reply!... :( now it says the 
     circle()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'circle' referenced before assignment

Comment: @user539075 Whoops, that is probably caused by me reusing circle (didn't realise the function was called circle). You probably want to do `for circleObject in mylist` or some other name.

Comment: MR.DUCK ? WOW! How can I thank you ?! THIS was almost a miracle. never thought I would get a right answer..thank you!
Now I will finish the other parts, its a mini LED screen and the words are movving...